# Maintain Checkout Across Merge

Tags: clearcase

I have a file checked out unreserved, and am looking to merge it to the newest version, but not check it in.

IE, I have a file I have made extensive (but not complete) changes to, and want to merge it up to the current version (which also has extensive changes).  I do not want to check it in because it would break other folks projects.

Is this even possible / how would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change your config spec in order to add an `mkbranch` option:
(assuming base ClearCase here, not UCM ClearCase)

```
 element * .../aPrivateBranch/LATEST
 element /path/to/file .../aBranch/LATEST -mkbranch aPrivateBranch
 element * /main/0 -mkbranch aPrivateBranch
```

That way, a checkin of your file would:

- trigger the merge with the LATEST version of the branch you are currently in ('`aBranch`')
- check a new version in *another* branch ('`aPrivateBranch`'), not disturbing your colleagues.

And you would continue other works in a private branch.